# Subversive installation

Tags: eclipse, subversive

When I use Eclipse marketplace to try to reinstall subversive which I used to use with my old version of Eclipse (I think it was Kepler) I get the following exception:

```
Unexpected exception while verifying features: Profile not locked due to exception: C:\Program Files\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.jee.profile\.lock (Access is denied)
Profile not locked due to exception: C:\Program Files\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.jee.profile\.lock (Access is denied)
Profile not locked due to exception: C:\Program Files\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.jee.profile\.lock (Access is denied)
Profile not locked due to exception: C:\Program Files\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.jee.profile\.lock (Access is denied)
```

What is this exactly telling me? I'm not sure what the Access denied thing is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Did the user you used to install your old Eclipse a different one compared to the one you're using now?
Investigate if the account that's currently running your Eclipse installation has enough permissions to create a lock file in a path like \p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.jee.profile.lock.
Try to manually remove this file if it exists.

I also found an interesting blog post by Rob Warner on Grailbox explaining another possible solution to your issue http://www.grailbox.com/2012/04/eclipse-insufficient-access-privileges-to-apply-this-update/

Here an extract from it

> In case anyone wants to workaround it manually, go to:
>
> eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\SDKProfile.profile
>   Edit the most recent profile file
>   Find the section in comment #1
>   Remove the line:
>   
>   Now start Eclipse and update it

Comment: I am using the same user all that I have changed on the user settings side since the last time I installed it was I gave that user full control, ability to Modify and ability to write.
I deleted the mentioned file and still the same exception.